# Getting Class Cast exception with custom impersonation in websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am writing a custom impersonation in Websphere 8.5. 
I am getting class cast exception at:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
PortletServiceHome pshimpersonate = (PortletServiceHome)    ctx.lookup(ImpersonationService.JNDI_NAME);
```

The error is: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.wps.services.portletserviceregistry.home.PortletServiceHomeImpl incompatible with com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.PortletServiceHome

Please suggest how to fix this error. I checked online but not getting a proper help.

Comment: Got this working. I found my class loading policy got changed to parent last. Changed that back to parent first and the above exception was gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.wps.services.portletserviceregistry.home.PortletServiceHomeImpl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729256/java-lang-classcastexception-com-ibm-wps-services-portletserviceregistry-home-p)